# Mongodb multi index search reduced performance

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I have a question about the reduced performance of an index query.  I have a collection indexed by two fields ‘COLOR’ and ‘FLAVOR’.  The collection is rather hefty, weighing in at 27M documents.  When I query the collection using each field separately I get blazing faster returns

```
collection.find({'COLOR': 'BLUE'}).count()

collection.find({'FLAVOR': 'SWEET'}).count()
```

When I combine these fields into a single query I get a huge degradation in performance.  Essentially the query runs indefinitely (w/o error).

```
collection.find({'COLOR': 'BLUE’},{'FLAVOR': 'SWEET'}).count()
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: did you used single index on those fields or compound index?

Comment: I used a single index.

Comment: In your case you have to define a compound index collection.createIndex({'COLOR': 1, 'FLAVOR' : 1})

Comment: Might just be a typo, but in your combined query, your syntax is actually querying for docs where COLOR is BLUE and then projecting the FLAVOR field of each doc and then counting that. You'd need to put both fields into a single object: `collection.find({COLOR: 'BLUE', FLAVOR: 'SWEET'}).count()`

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK.  The typo is in my translation, not the working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large difference in performance is likely due to needing to load documents from disk into memory. Assuming that your combined query is written incorrectly, and you meant for the query to be equivalent to

```
db.collection.count({ "COLOR" : "BLUE", "FLAVOR" : "SWEET" })
```

i.e. count the number of documents where `COLOR` is `"BLUE"` and `FLAVOR` is `"SWEET"`, MongoDB will choose one of the indexes on `COLOR` and `FLAVOR` to help fulfill the query. The choice will be made based on comparing the performance of the two empirically; it doesn't matter which one is chosen for this answer, so we will assume the query uses the index `{ "COLOR" : 1 }` and compare with

```
db.collection.count({ "COLOR" : "BLUE" })
```

The latter query just needs to look at the number of document pointers in the index BTree node for `"COLOR" : "BLUE"`. The former query will use the BTree to find the documents where `"COLOR" : "BLUE"`, but then must load each document and check if `"FLAVOR" : "SWEET"`. The index on `FLAVOR` can't be used for the latter operation because it maps from `FLAVOR` values to documents, not the other way around.

You can't see this happening directly because `.count` returns an integer, but it's almost the same thing going on when you compare the covered query

```
db.collection.find({ "COLOR" : "BLUE" }, { "_id" : 0, "COLOR" : 1 })
```

with the query

```
db.collection.find({ "COLOR" : "BLUE", "FLAVOR" : "SWEET" }, { "_id" : 0, "COLOR" : 1 })
```

I'd suggest trying both of those queries with `.explain` and comparing `n`, `nscanned`, and `nscannedObjects`.

You can produce the count `db.collection.count({ "COLOR" : "BLUE", "FLAVOR" : "SWEET" })` just using a compound index on `{ "COLOR" : 1, "FLAVOR" : 1 }`, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks wdberkeley.  This explanation is very clear and helpful!